# iOS 6- : Facebook API

Tags: ios, facebook-graph-api, ios6

I'm developing a application that integrates with Facebook.
I read about integrating in ios 6, ok. 
I downloaded the SDK and came with samples. I opened `"Scrumptious"`, but it's for iOS 4.3!!

So, two questions:

1. There is any sample for iOS 6?
2. How can I develop my application that integrates with iOS 6 and others iOS, using Facebook SDK?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The latest version of the Facebook SDK works on all Apple-supported versions of iOS, i.e. 4.3+. If the device is using iOS 6 and you request your permissions in an appropriate fashion (ie, read first, write later) then it will use Apple's built-in Facebook support and the username/password the user has supplied elsewhere. However it'll also work on iOS 4 and 5 devices that don't have that support, supplying an appropriate in-app prompt or paging out momentarily to the Facebook app as appropriate.

Use of the Facebook SDK is therefore optional for accessing Facebook from iOS 6 but is likely a good idea because:

- it also works under iOS 4 and 5; and
- it supplies a lot of pre-built dialogues for common Facebook tasks.

So although Scrumptious will work on iOS 4.3 it is using the latest version of the SDK and will use the OS-level support if available.

One of the distinguishing features of the latest SDK versus the older ones is that `FBSession` now has a concept of the `activeSession`, i.e. it has singleton-like features that support a global modal session. That was added publicly [in June last year](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk/blob/e82ebec7eab5261335ece7f65542c8bff645abd0/src/FBSession.h). Scrumptious makes use of that feature, for example on lines 94, 130, 144, 152 and 159 of SCAppDelegate.m.

So to answer your question directly: you've quite probably already downloaded the correct SDK. You'd write exactly the same code to work with it under iOS 4, 5 or 6. The samples like Scrumptious are a good place to start.

Comment: current Scrumptious example is not working for iOS below 6. It uses FBLoginView which does not open anything in iOS5 and below. Can you tell am I missing something or its problem with FB SDK or its designed to behave like that only?

Answer (score 1):

If you want a great tutorial, you can start with Ray Wenderlich's site.  They have a good beginning tutorial using the social framework.  I actually bought his book iOS 6 by tutorial.  It helped me make an app for a friend that integrates Facebook and twitter.  It really helps you understand the social framework.

http://www.raywenderlich.com/

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to integrate with the ios6 SocialKit? You don't need to download an SDK for that, it's built into the OS. I would recommend using Share Kit if you want to support older ios versions.